# SSL certificate in IIS for one site, all sites responds to https request

Tags: ssl, iis, https

I have multiple sites running on my IIS, now for one of the websites (SiteB) we need to support ssl requests. I have enabled it editing bindings for the website but this causes that all sites of my IIS if are requested with https:// loads web site of siteB.

I have only one IP for all sites.

For example my bidings are the next

```
Site A
IP  Port HostName
*     80 www.sitea.com

Site B
IP Port Hostname
*   443 www.siteb.com
*    80 www.siteb.com
```

If I type https://www.siteb.com in my browser it works correctly, but if I type https://www.sitea.com in the browser, siteb webpage is loaded with the hostname of sitea.

How Can I make that only https://www.siteb.com responds to https requests on my IIS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969%28v=ws.10%29.aspx very useful especially in your precise case.

appcmd set config /section:httpRedirect /enabled:true /destination:contoso.com <--obviously change to your page and if it's only case of child page : appcmd set config /section:httpRedirect /childOnly:true additionally you can add parameters from appcmd /?.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: oh ok sorry then :  appcmd set config /section:httpRedirect /enabled:true /destination:http://www.contoso.com <--obviously change to your page and if it's only case of child page  : appcmd set config /section:httpRedirect /childOnly:true

Comment: Please use the edit link on your answer to add additional information

Comment: Thanks Michal. But i have 128 sites in my IIS and only one have SSL certificate. Do I have to do a redirect for each? Is not redundant that a site redirect to itself?

Comment: ok then second approach edit web.config :

<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>

Comment: or last option : 

<html>
<head><title>Redirecting...</title></head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function redirectHttpToHttps()
{
    var httpURL= window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    var httpsURL= "https://" + httpURL;
    window.location = httpsURL;
}
redirectHttpToHttps();
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Someone who can help me with this issue?